# How do I display different input boxes based on choices from an option box?

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, onchange, display

I'm trying to create a form that allows you to input your SAT or ACT scores. Once you select which test you took, it should display different follow up questions based on whether the test you selected was an SAT or ACT. Here is what I have so far. It's almost working, but not quite. Here's the code I have. The drop-down box works fine, but I'm having trouble displaying the follow up questions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of the database:

- "test_id"    "test_name"      "test_type"
- 1           "Jun 2017 ACT"    "ACT"
- 2           "Apr 2017 ACT"    "ACT"
- 3           "Jun 2017 SAT"    "SAT"
- 4           "May 2017 SAT"    "SAT"

The drop down box displays the test_name, and captures the test_id as the value and the test_type as the rel.

```js
function test_scores() {
  var test_type = document.getElementById('test_name').rel;
  if (test_type = "ACT") {
    act_scores.style.display = "block";
  }
  if (test_type = "SAT") {
    sat_scores.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.act_scores {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
}

.sat_scores {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
}
```

```html
<form id="msform" onSubmit="return validate();" action="" class="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <h2 class="page-title legend">Score Information</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px;"><label>Add Scores:</label>
        <div class="select span5 no-float noMarginLeft">
          <select name="test_name" id="test_name" onchange=test_scores() required="required" style="width:100%;background:#fff;">
        <option value="">Test:</option>
        <option value="1" rel="SAT">Jun 2017 SAT</option>
        <option value="2" rel="ACT">Jun 2017 ACT</option>
        <option value="3" rel="SAT">May 2017 SAT</option>
        <option value="4" rel="ACT">Apr 2017 ACT</option>
          /* php code that is working */
        </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my_act_scores" class="act_scores">
      <div class="scores-content">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <label>English:<span style="color: red;width: 20px;">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="act_english" rows="1" class="form-control" required="required" id="act_english"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-content">
        <label>Math:<span style="color: red;width: 20px;">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="act_math" rows="1" class="form-control" required="required" id="act_math"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-content">
        <label>Reading:<span style="color: red;width: 20px;">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="act_reading" rows="1" class="form-control" required="required" id="act_reading"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-content">
        <label>Science:<span style="color: red;width: 20px;">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="act_science" rows="1" class="form-control" required="required" id="act_science"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-content">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="submit" name="act_submit" class="btn btn-green black">Submit</button>
        <span id="info"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="my_sat_scores" class="sat_scores">
      <div class="scores-content">
        <span class="close">×</span><label>Reading (out of 40):<span style="color: red;width: 20px;">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="sat_reading" rows="1" class="form-control" required="required" id="sat_reading"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class=" scores-content ">
        <label>Writing (out of 40):<span style="color: red;width: 20px; ">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="sat_writing " rows="1 " class="form-control " required="required " id="sat_writing "></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-content">
        <label>Math (out of 40):<span style="color: red;width: 20px; ">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="sat_math" rows="1" class="form-control" required="required" id="sat_math"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-content ">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="sat_submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-green black ">Submit</button><span id="info"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If there is no PHP issue, please REMOVE all PHP and add options and other HTML that is relevant to the question. The boxes in the snippet editor does NOT take script or style tags

Comment: Also you were missing an end quote and more - there are HTML errors you need to fix

Comment: OK, I got rid of php code. Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: can you tell me where my html errors are? the html is mostly working. the page loads. the drop down box functions correctly. I just can't get the right follow up questions to show.

Comment: I fixed the HTML - henrique fixed your script

Comment: Also rename the submit button - never call a form element submit since it hide the submit event handler

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the element in the dom to set style:

```
function test_scores(event) {
  var testTypeSelect = event.target;
  var test_type = testTypeSelect.options[testTypeSelect .selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel')
  if (test_type == "ACT") {
    document.getElementById('my_act_scores').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('my_sat_scores').style.display = "none";
  }
  if (test_type == "SAT") {
    document.getElementById('my_sat_scores').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('my_act_scores').style.display = "none";
  }
}
--//and
<select name="test_name" id="test_name" onchange=test_scores(event)
```

Comment: thanks. I made these changes. It's still not working exactly the way I want. I'm not certain my var test_type is calculating correctly. I'm going to work on that.

Comment: try document.getElementById('test_name').value. And put consoles or debugger to test.

Comment: The divs show with the above code - when I change the snippet to use it. What does "not working exactly the way I want" mean?

Comment: It's opening both the ACT and SAT follow up questions no matter which one I choose

Comment: So, my database table is basically like this:
test_id  test_name                test_type
1           Jun 2017 ACT            ACT
2           Apr 2017 ACT            ACT
3           Jun 2017 SAT            SAT
4           May 2017 SAT            SAT

So, the drop down box displays test_name and captures value test_id, but also sets rel to test_type.

Comment: I edit my answer. Change your code as my answer and the code will work.

Comment: OK, I modified the <option> to look more like the results of the php code. Does that help you see my problem?

Comment: Ah well, so I get it now. Again, I did a change to the answer to solve this problem now.

Comment: my problem now is not with the java. It's with the php for the rel. The code below is returning "undefined" when I alert on the test_type variable. test_name and test_id are working properly, so maybe I'm not allowed to assign rel in the same manner?               echo '<option value="'.$test->test_id .'" rel="'.$test->test_type .'">'.$test->test_name.'</option>';

Comment: I can't understand.

Comment: No, it's working now. I must have had something wrong. Thanks so much for all your help!!!

Comment: But, when you F12 and inspect the <option />, there is a rel value?